# Even if i migrate:fresh it shows me that the table already exists.. why?

Tags: mysql, laravel, database, migration

so i want to `php artisan migrate:fresh` but i get this error

> Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'roles' already exists

even if i drop the database from phpmyadmin, clean the cache and create the database again it still show the same message the migration for the table rows is the following one:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateRolesTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('roles', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->tinyInteger('status');
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('roles');
    }
}
```

the full error displayed:

> SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'roles' already exists (SQL: create table `roles` (`id` bigint unsigned not null auto_increment primary key, `name` varchar(255) not null, `guard_name` varchar(255) not null, `created_at` timestamp null, `updated_at` timestamp null) default character set utf8mb4 collate 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci')

Why is that? and what can or should I do?

Comment: Is there a different migration running that creates the table?

Comment: nope it is not from what i know, i will recheck now

Comment: nope it is not another migration running that creates it

Comment: hmmm, are you maybe using a package that might create that table? Can you copy/paste the output of your `php artisan migrate:fresh` command? Are other tables before it created successfully (check in phpMyAdmin)? Sure you dropped the correct database? Did you run `php artisan migrate:install` after dropping the db?

Comment: i updated it and im using something for permissions from spatie and it worked before installing this package but even so shouldnt it work if i migrate:fresh like drop all the tables and create new ones?

Comment: clear cache. Run `php artisan optimize:clear`. If it doesn't help run `composer dump:autoload`

Comment: Not sure if you need to publish migrations when using the Spatie package or if migrations are run from within the package. _If_ they run from within the package and you have a separate migration that creates the table they would collide. Try disabling your migration and check via phpmyadmin if the "roles" table still gets created

Comment: i still get the same error even after php artisan optimize:clear and composer dump-autoload

Comment: remove the migration containing the table `roles` and do a fresh migration. then check your database to see if the structure is to your liking.

Comment: from a fresh database you can run `php artisan migrate --pretend` which will show you all the migrations and the generated SQL that would have been ran ... should make it obvious if there are 2 migrations trying to create the same table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First drop **roles** table using this code `Schema::dropIfExists('roles');` then create.

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateRolesTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('roles'); //added
        Schema::create('roles', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->tinyInteger('status');
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('roles');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If it already exists before you did artisan migrate it will of course say this. Did you do migrate and it broke half way? You can reset it or just delete the table and try again (if you are in local dev and can delete it).

php artisan migrate:reset